# Can't get the picture to show in django

Tags: python, django, backend

```
<img
          class="img-fluid"
          alt="Responsive image"
          src="{% static 'product.image.url' %}"
        />
```

Cant get the picture to show on the web page.

Comment: I don't know but maybe try hard refresh?

Comment: Please try to post a [repro].

Comment: have you tried this `src="{{  product.image.url }}"` ?

Comment: Looks like you will display a media file and not a static asset. Try `{{ product.image.url }}`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need static.

```
<img class="img-fluid"
          alt="Responsive image"
          src="{{ product.image.url }}"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but did you add {% load static %} in the file.